# Reflective call occurred when using Aux pattern with type selection

Tags: scala, type-safety, aux-pattern

Consider the following exmaple:

```
sealed trait Granularity
object Granularity {

  case object Full extends Granularity

  sealed trait Partial extends Granularity {
    type GranularityKey
  }

  case object StringGranularity extends Partial {
    override type GranularityKey = String
  }
}

sealed trait Test{
  type T <: Granularity
}
object Test {

  type Aux[TT <: Granularity] = Test{ type T = TT }

  case object Cmp extends Test{
    override type T = StringGranularity.type
  }

  case object Fll extends Test{
    override type T = Full.type
  }
}
     
case class Tst[Gran <: Partial, T <: Test.Aux[Gran]](t: T#T#GranularityKey)
                                                          ^
                                                          |___Advanced language feature: reflective call
```

Idea signals about some reflective call occured in the type selection `T#T#GranularityKey`.

Could you please explain what exactly reflective call would occur here? So is it actually typesafe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, because of next `type Aux[TT <: Granularity] = Test{ type T = TT }` - basically you say here there is some `Test` that should have defined type alias `T` in it. I think compiler logic here similar to [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) in Scala implementation. For instance you can define `type Foo{ def bar(): Unit}` and try to next

```
class FooImpl {
  def bar(): Unit = println("Bar")
}
val foo: Foo = new FooImpl
foo.bar()
```

As you can see `FooImpl` does not inherits nothing, but still assignable for type `Foo`, because it satisfies condition of having method `bar`, but because of JVM restrictions or byte-code restrictions - `foo.bar()` invocation will be reflective, meaning though Java Reflection API. But, non the less this approach is completely type-safe.

Maybe, Idea because of this also thinks that type alias `T` inside `Test` trait will be invoked though Reflection API.

Comment: Probably that's an Idea bug, scalac does not print it when `-Xlog-reflective-calls`. But does it when using your case.

Comment: @SomeName Yes, make sens. Thank you for update!